# Update titleLabel UIButton

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel

I have a UIButton with a titleLabel, for example, like this: `@"Download it!"`

I would like after my download is finished, update the titleLabel of my button with another text, for example, like this: `@"Already downloaded!"`

I can change the state (enable or not) but impossible to refresh / update the titleLabel of the UIButton.

Any idea how to do this ? I tried `[myButton setNeedsDisplay];` but it doesn't work.

Thank for your suggestions and help.

**UPDATE 1:**
Solution:

```
[yourButton setTitle:<#(NSString *)#> forState:<#(UIControlState)#>]
```

Comment: Are you using [button setTitle:<#(NSString *)#> forState:<#(UIControlState)#>] to update it?

Comment: +1 for both, thank you all!

Comment: @Lapinou. .One suggestion. If you got answer of your question, better to accept an answer (any one here).. so that the question will not go in "Unanswered questions".. Hope you understand..

Comment: @achievelimitless You are providing answer for UIButton's different states like Normal or Highlighted, but not on when the download completes. Its not necessary that the download will be completed when the button is Pressed or highlighted.

Comment: @Lapinou Look at my answer. This is not related to UIButtonStates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
[yourButton setTitle:<#(NSString *)#> forState:<#(UIControlState)#>]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the text in a button's title label.

```
[aButton setTitle:@"Already downloaded!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

For more information on the topic, and the full list of control states, see this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uicontrol_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIControlState

Answer (score 2):

All the example explained with this post explains the change of title on button's various state like `UIControlStateNormal`, `UIControlStateHighlighted`but it is not doing it on download complete.

The simplest way is to keep notify your `viewController` that the some process (the download) is finished. Then you change the button Title as required.

May be try this code.

1. Add a button & a Notification observer in your ViewController `viewDidLoad` as

   ```
   self.someButton.title = @"Download Now"; // set the button title

   // Add notification Observer
   [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(notifyDownloadComplete:) 
                                               name:@"DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"
                                             object:nil];
   ```
2. Now define the target method of the Observer to perform the Button title Change as

   ```
   -(void)notifyDownloadComplete:(NSNotification*)note {
       self.someButton.title = @"Already Downloaded";
   }
   ```
3. Now add a Download Method via GCD & then post the notification once it is completed.

   ```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
      //Here your non-main thread. Try Downloading something
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      //Here you returns to main thread.
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" 
                                                          object:nil];
          });
      });
   ```

This will change the title of `self.someButton` to whatever you want, as in this case as `Already Downloaded`.

Hope that helps.